# How to get per interface and protocol (IPv6/IPv4) statistics in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, prometheus, ipv6

I am using prometheus / prometheus node exporter to monitor servers. This gives an easy insight in

- ipv6 packets received/sent in total
- ipv4 packets received/sent in total
- total number of bytes received/sent per interface

The problem is that IPv6/IPv4 statistics seem to be only "global" in Linux and not per interface. I was thinking about correlating the different statistics, but from the global stats I can only get a factor - which is likely very skewed on the per interface level.

I checked the typical stats in /proc, but did not find anything suitable.

So how can I get statistics over IPv6 packets sent/received on a particular device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know prometheus.  But on a very low level you can get interface statistics on Linux

- for IPv4 from /proc/self/net/dev
- for IPv6 /proc/self/net/dev_snmp6/*interface*

Answer (score -1):

use iptraf-ng

```
apt install iptraf-ng
```

and then run `iptraf-ng`

Comment: I am not looking for a real time traffic analyser, but to be able to say how many bytes IPv6 packets were transferred on a specific interface. And the same for IPv4.